# MySQL search in 3rd table through relation table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relation

Let's say I'm having three tables as follows:

- PRODUCT table (P) has ID, NAME
- CATEGORY table (C) has ID, NAME
- RELATION table (R) has ID, PRODUCT_ID, CATEGORY_ID

I'm currently on the product list page and I want a function to be able to search products by its category name.

```
select P.* 
from P
where P.id in (select group_concat(distinct R.product_id) from C join R on C.id=R.category_id where C.name like '%something%')
```

The above SQL will only give me the first match, but running the query in the brackets will return more than one id. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group_concat()` is unnecessary:

```
select P.* 
from P
where P.id in (select R.product_id
               from C join
                    R
                    on C.id = R.category_id
               where C.name like '%something%'
              );
```

Your query is fine, but it would more typically be written as:

```
select P.*
from P join
     R
     on P.id = R.product_id join
     C
     on C.id = R.category_id
where C.name like '%something%';
```

This version could return duplicates, if more than one category matched the `like` condition.

Comment: You are right! remove it and it works! Anyway other way to write this query?

Comment: thanks a lot! I did tried the second sql but unfortunately i also need to list all the categories that each product belongs. my full sql is:


select p.*, group_concat(distinct c.id) as category_ids from p left join r on r.product_id=p.id left join c on c.id=r.category_id where ### group by p.id


### will be the query i'm looking for in this question. If I place your 2nd solution into the ### then i won't be able to get all the category ids for each product.